# How do I cycle words from an array in sequence JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I created an automatic slideshow in a html webpage, i want to display some text outside the images. This is the script I'm using currently, I had asked on quora they gave me this script

```
var words = ['beautiful', 'cool', 'amazing']; 
var t = setInterval(function() { 
  var randomNumber = Math.round( Math.random() * (words.length-1) ); 
  $('#changing').html( words[ randomNumber ] ); 
}, 2000);
```

But this is randomizing the caption, and I want it in sequence so that it displays it to the approp image. Can someone please help me?

Comment: do you have an example of the wanted result?

Comment: i've linked my webpage in the below comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you want to keep track of the previous index used in the array, maybe try something like this?

```js
var words = ['beautiful', 'cool', 'amazing'];
var i = 0; 
var t = setInterval(function() { 
  $('#changing').html( words[i] ); 
  i++
  if (i >= words.length) i=0;
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont really know much about javascript, so can you explain what exactly this will do?

Comment: So what this does is start with an integer i at an index of 0. words[0] = 'beautiful',it then adds 1 each loop of this function, so the next turn is 1, words[1] = 'cool', it does this until it reaches the length of the array (3) and reverts back to 0.

Comment: var words = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test3']; this is my array when i applied your script, it skips the first word test1

Comment: apologies, i placed the iterator (i++) too early in theprevious example

Comment: if it would help you this is my webpage 
http://worldoffun.great-site.net/Way%20To%20Fun!/index.html
you can inspect the code

Comment: @AaryanG thankyou, I updated my code above to reflect the requirement. The "$('#changing').html( words[i] ); " needed to be called before i++

Comment: Wow it works thank you so much! btw if I have any more questions where can i contact you?

Comment: no problem! yes of course, ill try to respond when I can :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221735/discussion-between-aaryan-g-and-richard-price).